# Configuring KDevelop

Tags: c++, c, kdevelop

I have just installed KDevelop Ver 5.1.1 on Windows 10 64-bit. How do I compile C & C++programs with it? I am a complete beginner in programming. Please do explain in simple words.

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't the place to ask for programming tutorials; it is mostly here to help you solve specific problems. There are plenty of intro-to-coding websites out there after all.

Comment: For what it's worth, we have this question covered here: https://userbase.kde.org/KDevelop4/Manual/WindowsSetup

Answer (score 3):

Since you are a complete beginner to programming I would suggest that you instead find your self a copy of Microsoft Visual Studio. I believe they may still have a free option, but you will need to look into that. It is a much easier system to get working on Windows.

Now if you really want to get KDevelop Working it is going to take some serious effort on your part.

You will need to:

1. Install working C && C++ Compilers (I believe that KDevelop is designed to work with `Clang`) [Tutorial on How to install Clang](http://blog.johannesmp.com/2015/09/01/installing-clang-on-windows-pt1/)
2. Install `cmake` or a similar build system in order for Develop to be able to execute builds for you. [Install Instructions from the cmake website.](https://cmake.org/install/)
3. Setup KDevelop to build using Clang & Cmake: [Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=47xdLegd3z4)
4. Have Patience.
5. Remember, Google is your friend.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Google is not helping. Or may be I'm not searching efficiently. I will try your suggestions and see if it works.

Comment: The [VS Community Edition](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/community/) is still free. Make sure to follow the licencing requirements of the Community edition for commercial development, though.

Comment: KDevelop doesn't directly depend on a compiler. You can use whatever compiler CMake supports. So, KDevelop can cope with Microsoft C++ compiler and CMake perfectly fine.

Comment: That is true, but the kdevelop website mentions that it's autocomplete is supported by clang. I figured that would be a helpful feature to have functional for someone new.